# MS ACCESS VBA Move/Copy Files

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the below code to reference a table that has full path information to move (or copy) files from 1 location to another. However, it's not moving anything, but is completing per my Debug.Print message (Move Complete 2/22/2021 1:22:41 PM). Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Additionally, I'd like to build the folder/subfolder structure where the file was located in the source...but don't know how to achieve that...and pointers on how to do this?

```
Sub copy_files_from_table()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim source As String
Dim destination As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database

 SQL = "select * from file_test"
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

 source = RS!LocalFile
 destination = "C:\Temp\Test"


 While Not RS.EOF

If Dir(source, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 
    objFSO.CopyFolder source, destination:=destination  '
    
 Debug.Print "Move Folder Command Complete From: " & destination

Else

 End If
    
 RS.MoveNext

Wend

Debug.Print "Move Complete " & Now()
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help provided.

Comment: is `!localFile` a field in the recordset? If so that probably needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: `source = RS!LocalFile` should be inside the loop so that it updates with each row

Comment: Appreciate the quick answer:

Isn't   objFSO.CopyFolder source:=source, destination:=destinationFolder  
 inside the loop? Or am i missing something.

Comment: `Source` is assigned a value outside of the loop and then never changes so it is always checking the same value in the `if`

Comment: Don't bother with source variable, just reference `RS!LocalFile` inside the loop.

Comment: To build same file path, will have to parse the path string and create folder at each level, first checking if folder exists. http://msaccessgurus.com/VBA/Code/MakeAPath.htm

Comment: Also, think need backslash at end of folder path.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get this to work. I manipulated the code enough to get an error "Path not found". In my rs!LocalFile, the table has the full path as well as the document. Example: C:\Temp\Home\Test.txt ....if this is in the table, I need to move the file in C:\Temp\Test.txt to D:\Temp\Home\Test.txt. ....But I can't get the base part to just move to the root of D:\Temp\Test.txt.

Comment: I wrote this but it's still not moving to D:\Temp\Test.txt

'code'    While Not RS.EOF


   If Dir(RS!LocalFile, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
      objFSO.CopyFile RS!LocalFile, destination
        
    Debug.Print "Move Folder Command Complete From: " & destination

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have gotten the following code to work on file paths <259; however, anything longer is causing the code to error. Since I'm pretty green on coding:) any suggestions how I can get around the long file path names?

```
Sub CopyFilesFromTable2()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim source As String
Dim destination As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim SQL As String
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database



 'Test Table
  SQL = "select * from file_test"

 'Prod Table
 'SQL = "select * from file"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set db = CurrentDb
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

 source = RS!LocalFile
File = VBA.FileSystem.Dir(source)
destination = "D:\Temp\Test\"

With RS

If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then

.MoveLast
.MoveFirst

While (Not .EOF)

FSO.CopyFile RS!LocalFile, destination

.MoveNext

Wend


 End If

.Close

End With


ExitSub:

Set RS = Nothing
'set to nothing
MsgBox "Done!"

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err, vbCritical

Resume ExitSub


End Sub
```